# python regex preserve specified special characters only

Tags: python, regex

I've been looking for a way to isolate special characters in a regex expression, but I only seem to find the exact opposite of what I'm looking for. So basically I want to is something along the lines of this:

```
import re
str = "I only want characters from the pattern below to appear in a list ()[]' including quotations"

pattern = """(){}[]"'-"""
result = re.findall(pattern, str)
```

What I expect from this is:

```
print(result)
#["(", ")", "[", "]", "'"]
```

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'[^\w\s]', str)`

Comment: So, use `pattern = r"""[][(){}"'-]"""`

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need regex for this when it can be done without regex?

```
>>> str = "I only want characters from the pattern below to appear in a list ()[]' including quotations"
>>> pattern = """(){}[]"'-"""
>>> [x for x in str if x in pattern]
['(', ')', '[', ']', "'"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's for learning purposes (regex isn't really the best way here), then you can use:

```
import re

text = "I only want characters from the pattern below to appear in a list ()[]' including quotations"
output = re.findall('[' + re.escape("""(){}[]"'-""") + ']', text) 
# ['(', ')', '[', ']', "'"]
```

Surrounding the characters in `[` and `]` makes it a regex character class and `re.escape` will escape any characters that have special regex meaning to avoid breaking the regex string (eg: `]` terminating the characters early or `-` in a certain place causing it to act like a character range).

Answer (score 0):

Several of the characters in your set have special meaning in regular expressions; to match them literally, you need to backslash-escape them.

```
pattern = r"""\(\)\{\}\[]"'-"""
```

Alternatively, you could use a character class:

```
pattern = """[]-[(){}"']"""
```

Notice also the use of a "raw string" `r'...'` to avoid having Python interpret the backslashes.

Answer (score -3):

This regex that solved my problem:

```
pattern = r"""[(){}\[\]"'\-]"""
```

<sub>*Posted on behalf of the question asker*</sub>